# Most pythonic way to create bytes() of size N with non-zero initial value?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I could do something like

```
initialValue = 0x42
width = 113
someBytes = bytes([initialValue] * width)
```

This wastes time creating an intermediate list just to throw it away though.

or

```
someBytes = bytearray(width)
for n in range(width):
  someBytes[n] = initialValue
```

But that's highly un-functional, and starts with an initial value of zero, which will just be immediately replaced, and I need to use a bytearray for the assignment to work.

Is there a more python/simple/terse way to accomplish this?

(python3 btw)

**Follow Up:**

I ended up using the `bytes([initialValue]) * width` approach. I think the only thing that is "less than obvious" is the need to use a regular list of short lived state to create a byte array with an initial value, but that's independent of the width allocation, and is consistent with some of the other python collections.

I did do some timing that was interesting. One would expect the stretched bytes to be faster than the bytes created from a stretched list.

```
>>> timeit("bytes([initial]) * width",
...  "width = 256; initial = 0x42", number=100000)
0.11861954815685749
```

vs

```
>>> timeit("bytes([initial] * width)",
...   "width = 256; initial = 0x42", number=100000)
0.5535310138948262
```

As the size of `width` goes up, the difference becomes more and more pronounced. Another interesting approach that I tried was using a comprehension for creation. I was surprised it just how slow this was:

```
>>> timeit("bytes(initial for _ in range(width))",
...   "width = 256; initial = 0x42", number=100000)
2.3924577180296183
```

As the width went up this one really spread away from the original. Since my initialValue was determined programatically, I was not in a position to use that approach, but its speed is actually quite fast, which surprised me a bit, that the overhead of creating the one element bytes from a list was that significant:

```
>>> timeit("b'\x42' * width",
...   "width = 256; initial = 0x42", number=100000)
0.010320456698536873
```

This is fully 10x faster than the otherwise fast, but non-literal solution.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Neither of your examples seem to do anything useful. The first makes a string representation of a Python list, which is probably not what you wanted, and your 2nd example results in `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`. Are you aware that `bytes` is just another name for `str`?

Comment: It occurs to me we must be talking about Python 3. It would be good to specify that in the question, because it's totally different in Python 2. Example 2 still won't work though, I think you'd want `bytearray`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do the multiplication after creating the `bytes`:

```
bytes([initialValue])*width
```

Comment: Also just `b'\x42'*113` if it is just a constant.